# Сортировка выбором. Почему работает функция с циклом for, но отдельно цикл не работает?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка

```
myArr=[0,5,-10,-6,3,2,18]
```

## этот цикл выдает первое значение в массиве, но не наименьшее:

```
min=myArr[0]
for i in range(1,len(myArr)):
    if myArr[i] < min: myArr[i]=min
print(min)
```

## а тут все хорошо:

```
def minimum(array):
    min=array[0]
    for i in range(1,len(array)):
        if array[i] < min: array[i]=min
    print(min)
minimum(myArr)
```

Comment: Не стоит использовать 'min' в качестве имени переменной - это имя существующей встроенной функции и его переопределение может привести к нежелательным побочным эффектам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не `myArr[i]=min` а `min = myArr[i]` и в функции тоже поменяйте операторы в присвоении местами. Просто так, как у Вас, получается Вы каждому элементу списка присваиваете значение его первого элемента.
В результате должно получиться примерно так:

```
myarr = [0, 5, -10, -6, 3, 2, 18]    
min_val = myarr[0]
for i in range(1, len(myarr)):
    if myarr[i] < min_val:
         min_val = myarr[i]
print(min_val)
```

> Слово `min` является зарезервированным (именем функции), не рекомендуется использовать зарезервированные имена для именования переменных.

#### Если использование индексов не обусловлено в задаче, то я сделал бы так:

```
myarr = [0, 5, -10, -6, 3, 2, 18]
min_val = myarr[0]

for item in myarr[1:]:
    if item < min_val:
        min_val = item

print(min_val)
```

Ну или так:

```
myarr = [0, 5, -10, -6, 3, 2, 18]
print(sorted(myarr)[0])
```

Comment: Благодарю за развернутое решение проблемы!

Comment: Лучше все-таки “min(myArr)” чем “sorted(myArr)[0]”

Comment: @MaxU, я исходил из того, что это должно быть имитацией работы функции `min()`

Answer (score 0):

```
myArr=[0, 5, -10, -6, 3, 2, 18]
min=myArr[0]

for item in myArr:
    if item < min:
        min = item

print(min)
-10
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ!